# how to receive image via OBEX directly into .NET CF application

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, bluetooth, obex

I'm trying to use InTheHand.Net library on iPaq 214 to start BluetoothListener or ObexListener and receive file (photo) from mobile phone directly into my application, but the listener does not receive the file at all. It's overriden with default Pocket Outlook "Unknown File" dialog, which offers to save the incoming file to some directory.

Is there any method how to disable this dialog (or Pocket Outlook BT service = obexinbx.dll) from handling the incoming file and handle the file in my own code using InTheHand.Net library?

Answer (score 1):

See the 32feet.NET documentation on this at http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=One%20Active%20Server  Hope that's what's required...

I'm the maintainer of said library. :-)

I've updated that documentation with some more details on the situation for devices with a Bluetooth stack from a different provider (Widcomm, Bluetopia), and for devices where a different OBEX server is used (HTC).

I'm hunting for the charging cable for my iPAQ to see if there's a checkbox in the Widcomm control-panel to disable the OBEx server.  I don't know of a programmatic way to disable the Widcomm OBEX server.  Maybe there's a Registry value that can be set...

Comment: this looks promising, but I'm not able to get PInvoke of DeviceIoControl working - it always returns false (or zero) as a result and doesn't write anything in the output buffer. Could you take a look on my code, please: https://gist.github.com/1442069 ?

Comment: Wierd...  I've added some more information to my original answer.  In brief the DeviceIoControl method will likely only work on devices with the default Microsoft Bluetooth stack and the iPAQ has the Widcomm stack.

Comment: I see... So is there any other possibility how to turn the default OBEX service off? I tried setting the registry IsEnabled value to 0, but it had no immediate effect and after reboot it's back to 1. I also tried other registry modifications, but without any success - most of the values are also reset back after restart.